# Error while Integrating 3rd Party API in my Magento Store

Tags: magento-1.9, error, api, external

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  on line 58 of below code

Below is the code.

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $price = $this->getConfigData('price'); // set a default shipping price maybe 0
    $price = 0;

    //var_dump($request);
    // $api_url = "http://www.eshipper.com/fetch_rates";
    // $api_username = "opsapi";
    // $api_password = "opsapipass";
    $api_url = $this->getConfigData('api');
    $api_username = $this->getConfigData('apiusername');
    $api_password = $this->getConfigData('apipassword');
    $increase_rate = $this->getConfigData('increaserate');
    $weight_class = $this->getConfigData('weightclass');

    //Case1: Price Depends on Country,State and Pin Code
    $destCountry = $request->getDestCountryId();
    $destRegion = $request->getDestRegionId();
    $destRegionCode = $request->getDestRegionCode();
    // print_r($destStreet = $request->getDestStreet()); echo ': Dest Street<br/>';
    $destStreet = $request->getDestStreet();
    $destCity = $request->getDestCity();
    $destPostcode = $request->getDestPostcode();
    $country_id = $request->getCountryId();
    $region_id = $request->getRegionId();
    //$region_code = $request->getRegionCode();
    $city = $request->getCity();
    $postcode = $request->getPostcode();

    $region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($region_id);
    $region_code = $region->getCode();

    $service_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$destPostcode.'&sensor=false';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($curl_response === false) {
        $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    $decoded = json_decode($curl_response);
    if (isset($decoded->response->status) && $decoded->response->status == 'ERROR') {
        die('error occured: ' . $decoded->response->errormessage);
    }

    $result = $decoded->results;
    $city_name = $result[0]->address_components[1]->long_name;

     if ($request->getAllItems()) {

        $total_item = count($request->getAllItems());
        $currency = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $prod_html = '';
        $count_row = 1;
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {

            if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem()) {
                continue;
            }

            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                $count_children = count($item->getHasChildren());
                $count_children_row = 1;
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {
                        $product_id = $child->getProductId();
                        $productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                        $ship_price = $productObj->getData('shipping_price'); //our shipping attribute code
                        //$price += (float)$ship_price;
                        $prd_name = str_replace('"',"'",$productObj->getName());
                        $prod_html .= '{"name":"'.$prd_name.'","sku":"'.$productObj->getSku().'","quantity":'.$item->getQty().',"weight":'.floor($item->getWeight()).',"weightUnit":"'.$weight_class.'","price":'.$item->getPrice().',"vendor":"null","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"fulfillment_service":"manual","product_id":"'.$product_id.'","variant_id":410333945}';
                        if($count_children_row<$count_children || $count_row<$total_item){
                            $prod_html .= ',';
                        }
                        $count_children_row++;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $product_id = $item->getProductId();
                $productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
                $prd_name = str_replace('"',"'",$productObj->getName());
                $prod_html .= '{"name":"'.$prd_name.'","sku":"'.$productObj->getSku().'","quantity":'.$item->getQty().',"weight":'.floor($item->getWeight()).',"weightUnit":"'.$weight_class.'","price":'.$item->getPrice().',"vendor":"null","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"fulfillment_service":"manual","product_id":"'.$product_id.'","variant_id":410333945}';
            }
            if($count_row<$total_item){
                $prod_html .= ',';
            }
            $count_row++;
        }
    }


    //$fileContents = '{"rate":{"origin":{"country":"CA","postal_code":"V3N4R3","province":"ON","city":"Burnaby","name":null,"address1":"90 Maverick","address2":null,"address3":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":null},"destination":{"country":"'.$destCountry.'","postal_code":"'.$destPostcode.'","province":"'.$destRegionCode.'","city":"'.$destCity.'","name":null,"address1":null,"address2":"","address3":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":""},"items":['.$prod_html.'],"currency":"'.$currency.'"}}';
    $fileContents = '{"rate":{"origin":{"country":"'.$country_id.'","postal_code":"'.$postcode.'","province":"'.$region_code.'","city":"'.$city.'","name":null,"address1":null,"address2":null,"address3":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":null},"destination":{"country":"'.$destCountry.'","postal_code":"'.$destPostcode.'","province":"'.$destRegionCode.'","city":"'.$city_name.'","name":null,"address1":null,"address2":"","address3":null,"phone":null,"fax":null,"address_type":null,"company_name":""},"items":['.$prod_html.'],"currency":"'.$currency.'","CART_NAME":"MAGENTO"}}';
    //print_r($fileContents); exit;

    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Content-Type: application/json',
                    'API_USERNAME: ' . $api_username,
                    'API_PASSWORD: ' . $api_password
                )
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fileContents);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    //print_r($data);exit;
    if ($data !== FALSE) {
        $data = json_decode($data, TRUE);
    } else {
        $data = "";
    }
    $rate_array = array();
    if (is_array($data) && sizeof($data['rates']) > 0) {
        foreach ($data['rates'] as $key => $value) {
            $price = $value['total_price'] * 0.01;
            $price_eship_inc = $price + ($price * $increase_rate * 0.01);
            $max_delivery_date = "";
            if (!empty($value['max_delivery_date'])) {
                $max_delivery_date = " (Delivered by: " . $value['max_delivery_date'] . ")";
            } else {
                $max_delivery_date = "";
            }
            $np_label_shipping = $value['service_name'] . $max_delivery_date;
            if($price_eship_inc!=0)
            {
                $rate = array(
                    'id' => "eShipper_" . $value['service_code'],
                    'label' => $np_label_shipping,
                    'cost' => $price_eship_inc,
                    'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
                );
                // $this->add_rate($rate);
                $rate_array[] = $rate;
                //print_r($rate);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $rate = array(
            'id' => "eShipper",
            'label' => "Shipping Rates Not Available",
            'cost' => 0.00,
            'calc_tax' => 'per_order'
        );
        //$this->add_rate($rate);
         //print_r($rate);
    }

    $handling = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/handling');
    $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
    $show = true;
    //print_r($rate_array);
    if($show){



        /*$method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
            $method->setPrice($price);
            $method->setCost($price);*/
            //echo $this->_code; exit;
            $i=0;
        foreach($rate_array as $value){
            $i++;
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setMethod($this->_code.$i);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $method->setMethodTitle($value['label']);
            $method->setPrice($value['cost']);
            $method->setCost($value['cost']);
            $result->append($method);
        }



    }else{
        $error = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_error');
        $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
        $error->setErrorMessage($this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg'));
        $result->append($error);
    }
    return $result;
}
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    return array('excellence'=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
}
}
```

SYSTEM.LOG

(3): Notice: Undefined offset:  0  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T08:10:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T08:10:59+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T08:13:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset:  0  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T08:13:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T08:13:07+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:48:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant LB - assumed 'LB'  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Shipping/Weightclass.php on line 33
2016-11-02T10:48:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant KG - assumed 'KG'  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Shipping/Weightclass.php on line 34
2016-11-02T10:48:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant GRAMS - assumed 'GRAMS'  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Shipping/Weightclass.php on line 35
2016-11-02T10:48:55+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Use of undefined constant OZ - assumed 'OZ'  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Shipping/Weightclass.php on line 36
2016-11-02T10:57:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset:  0  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:57:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:57:44+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:59:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset:  0  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:59:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T10:59:52+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T11:02:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined offset:  0  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T11:02:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58
2016-11-02T11:02:00+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object  in /home3/produdo3/public_html/qtscanada/app/code/community/Excellence/Ship/Model/Carrier/Excellence.php on line 58

Comment: can you share error with code or all file code?

Comment: @Abdul above code file is excellence.php . i will add system.log file